# aws certificate granted by amazon, instead of custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-certificate-manager

I am trying to create a custom domain name with AWS API Gateway, so that my Lambda function URL has a nice URL. With some help from a helpful YouTube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ESei6XQ7dMg), I succeeded to create a custom domain name, which invokes the regarding Lambda function by API Gateway. I requested an AWS certificate for the custom domain, which domain name is exactly the value of the custom domain (domain name: api.mycustomdomain.nl)

But, when I check the certificate of the custom domain, it gives a 'Not secure' warning, which is caused from an invalid certificate (as seen below). It says that the domain is granted to '*.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com' and is granted by Amazon. I expected that my new requested AWS certificate is being used, so that the 'granted by domain' has a value of 'api.mycustomdomain.nl'.

What am I missing here?

[image]